Site design and logo — Draft
After gathering your feedback and doing some research, I have spent some time working on the design for the site, and I am excited to share the result. Hope you like it, and I look forward to your feedback!
Bitcoin site design
The design is based around the universal bitcoin symbol and the lightning network, which is one of its most iconic characteristics. The Bitcoin logo was slightly modified to be unique to the site but still distinguished as the bitcoin logo everyone knows. The lightning network and blockchain is represented in the background as a simple connection of dots that can be representative of nodes.
Color scheme
The colors chosen are a palette inspired by the Bitcoin Orange.

Logo
As mentioned before, the logo is a slight variation from the universal logo paired with the Bitcoin title that uses Poppins Semibold as the font. A font that is geometrical and clean.

Favicon

Page Design


We hope you enjoy this design, but if something doesn’t feel right, now is your chance to share your feedback. This window for feedback will be open for one week. We will then work to incorporate feedback as best as we can, finalize things on our end, and lastly, deliver the design to your site.

Hi V2Blast, Catija, and Jose, I was just wondering whether you had an update on the status of this project and whether there was something else we could do to help.

Hi all, any update on this?

Sorry for the late reply. We are expecting the new theme to be live next week. I appreciate the feedback given and patience.

Update: Your new site design is live!

I agree with not altering the logo too much as it could be mistaken for an altcoin. Background looks good.
Sticking with the original #F7931A orange and 14 degree tilt inside a speech bubble is my suggestion.
Made a quick mockup below:

The SVG file Stephen's shared above is outdated and has some minor issues with the vector so I made a Figma file that has updated assets for the original bitcoin logo (not just the icon but also the wordmark and "B" on its own).
I detailed what very slight alterations I made in the File. I also included my mockup above if you wanted to use / modify it - it's all yours!
Figma file: https://www.figma.com/file/zMyIHY7iGVTpP8uc7prM5x/Bitcoin-logo?node-id=1%3A6
You can DM over at the Bitcoin Design slack mentioned by Murch if you need any help / feedback.

Thanks for taking the time to build a custom branding for the Bitcoin Stack Exchange! Here are some thoughts on logo and background.
Logo
I would suggest using the Bitcoin logo in its proper form, meaning #F7931A orange with a 14 degree tilt. You can find the SVG file for this here.
https://bitcoin.design/guide/getting-started/visual-language/#update-by-bitboy
In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with modifying the bitcoin logo when you are trying to conform it to an existing brand. But there isn't really an existing brand for Bitcoin Stack Exchange, so making modifications to it seems a little arbitrary in this context.
The way that the tips of the B have been extended and sharpened looks very harsh. They remind me of daggers or knives. It looks very dangerous and unfriendly. Since many in this community see bitcoin as the most open monetary network on the face of the earth and a beneficial technology for humanity, it makes more sense for the bitcoin logo to appear more friendly. Therefore, best to use the original logo in this situation.
Speech bubble logo
I think the speech bubble logo is a good idea, but I'd recommend using the original Bitcoin B, tilted and with the proper orange.
Background
We can say it represents a network of bitcoin nodes. It looks very standard B2B technology stock imagery, but it will get the job done.
Maybe try lightening background very slightly, or darkening text? Technically, the colors pass WCAG AA and AAA a11y requirements, but for some reason when I eyeball it just looks a little low-contrast. That might just be me. Not sure if others feel the same way.
https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=61605C&bcolor=F0EAE3

I don't have much of an eye for design myself, but when I had a look at this draft, I had a few concerns. The Bitcoin Logo is usually slanted 14° clockwise. There is a forkcoin of Bitcoin, essentially a scam, that uses an upright ₿ on a yellow background for its logo. The main color of the proposed scheme falls somewhere in the middle between Bitcoin Orange and that forkcoin's color.
The logo itself feels a bit too customized. Since there are scores of Bitcoin copycats, it might be better to stick closer to the original logo.
I asked a befriended member of the Bitcoin Design community for her thoughts. She provided the following questions and comments:

Bitcoin site design
Is the site design based on technical execution? I
like that there is inspiration from a branding standpoint but I wonder
if UX/UI strategies are considered.
Color scheme
Is this accessible? Has it been tested? Iterating on
Bitcoin Orange is an interesting idea but I am not sure these colors
meet web standards. This new Bitcoin Design Accessibility page
may be worth consideration.
Logo
If the plan is to go for geometrical and clean, this logo needs a
bit of tweaking. Bitcoin icons has been polished and may provide more
of the desired look and feel for this logo. There
are github and figma environments to build and share.
Page Design
Readability is a challenge. More space and visuals to
communicate would offer a much smoother user flow. It would be useful
to see flows and wireframes. From the screens shown it isn’t clear how
different personas may interact and make sense of the site. Bitcoin UI
Kit could be the best tool for the job here.

She also invited you to join the Bitcoin Design Slack, if you wanted to bounce a few ideas around, and suggested that probably a few of the 3,000+ members of the Bitcoin Design Community would be excited to help the effort.

As a non-designer, it reads that the response in some cases (e.g. page design) don't relate to the design/artwork itself, but rather to the layout of our platform, which this design is not touching. Is it possible to clarify whether these points are about the artwork before/after rather than about the entire layout of the page?

Sorry, I may have initially failed to convey that the layout is mostly fixed, but only the color scheme and artwork are up for a do-over. My friend thinks that "using bitcoin design icons and changing the logo could be the easiest wins here". The linked Bitcoin Icons are open source, free to use, and under an open license. If your designer were interested, she'd be happy to help "jam it out on figma sometime".

I'd like to echo Murch's concerns about the logo stylization in this draft. As a site devoted to technical Q/A help, I feel that we should stick to the well-adopted open-source standards, rather than trying to break the mould with something novel/fancier. Specifically:

I agree that including the 14° clockwise tilt is highly preferable, and also important in regards to maintaining a distinct brand amongst the many imitators/scams.
Likewise, keeping the 'orange' colour in the colour palette as close to #F7931A as possible is preferable to differentiate against imitators/scams.
The angled ends on the vertical and horizontal lines extending out of the 'B' look odd to me, and break away from the normative design. I think sticking to flat ends is highly preferable (for the vertical lines, at the very least).

On the positive side, I really do like the connected dots in the top left, I think they are a simple but effective element that represents the P2P nature of the Bitcoin network well.
Thank you for your work on this, I am excited to see the final product.
